# c:param does not append the expected value, it appends %24%7bkey%7d instead of evaluated value of ${key}

Tags: jsp, jstl

The following is not working

```
<%session.setAttribute("key", ${key});%>


<c:redirect url="/example/request/first.jsp"> 
    <c:param name="send" value="done"/>
    <c:param name="key"><%= session.getAttribute("key") %></c:param>
</c:redirect>
```

result: "send=done&key=%24%7bkey%7d"

How would I pass my session attribute in so that the correct value would come across?

*update - What is happening is that I am saving a uploaded file to a directory on the server.  I don't know how to accomplish that using a ajax call so I am using the form post method.

My ajax call which saves the record to the database is executing before my form post so the key(for that record) is lost once I get forwarded to the jsp page taking care of the file upload.

I am trying to redirect to my main page from there preserving the key so that I can load the record for the user.  I was hoping that maybe session data could accomplish that for me by keeping the key from the ajax call to the form post.  Messy I know...  My solution needs to work on at least Internet explorer 8.

Comment: are you sure you have not any problem in set attribue in session?

Comment: Update Sorry I am having trouble setting the attribute as well.

Comment: Using JSP EL inside a scriptlet is non-sensical.

Comment: use `"${sessionScope.key}"` instead of `<%= session.getAttribute("key") %>` Although i don't think any change occured. but test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you mixing taglibs/EL with oldschool *scriptlets*?

Just use [Expression Language (EL, those `${}` things)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) exclusively.

```
<c:param name="key" value="${key}" />
```

I strongly recommend to configure your webapp to completely disable *scriptlets* (those `<% .. %>` things) by the appropriate entry in `web.xml`, so that this kind of mistakes can be avoided in the future.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/)

Comment: Do you know how to set a session attribute using tag libraries or expression language?

Comment: `<c:set var="sessionAttributeName" scope="session" value="${someValue}"/>`. But setting session attributes has nothing to do in a JSP. It should be done by the controller.

Comment: Please click the "Expression Language" link in my answer. The `${key}` already resolves to a page/request/session/application attribute. I'm not seeing any point of re-setting it as session attribute using a scriptlet here.